# why ReactDOM is not defined in my helloworld program?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am the new learner of Reactjs. I am trying to execute hello world program in the browser.
But I got an error. i.e

> react-dom.min.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__SECRET_DOM_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED' of undefined

And my code is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <title>Hello React!</title>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react-dom.min.js"></script> 
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="example"></div>
 <script type="text/babel">
  ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('example')
  );
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can not understand the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use react-dom.min.js after react.min.js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <title>Hello React!</title>
 
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react-dom.min.js"></script> 
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="example"></div>
 <script type="text/babel">
  ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('example')
  );
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```